# VS2013 to VS2015 All Reference Broken

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 website I'm trying to open in Visual Studio 2015 with several reference Class Library projects and a lot of used nuget packages. All of the references that are NuGet packages have an exclamation mark on them and I have 854 errors in my solution.

I've tried restoring all of the NuGet packages but it say's they're up to date. Is there some trick when opening MVC 4 sites in VS2015?